# Products recognition with OPENCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm developing a program in Python that detects a particular product on store shelves. I used SIFT alghoritm to get the descriptors and then I used a knnMatcher to match up the SIFT features. I applied the ratio test to eliminate false matches and then I apply a threeshold to decide if the number of matches found is enough. However I have a particular problem in this situation:

[image]

The result is that it found enough matches of the Nesquik product in the train image , even if the two products are not the same(indeed the below part of the image is different). 
What is the best way to approach the situation? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is that because you don't have the same image on the right, so your algorithm just finds the most similar image among all given images? In this case, is it more desirable that the algorithm tells that it cannot find exactly the same image? Maybe you can set a similarity or distance threshold for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should incorporate text extraction and recognition for your task. It may happen that multiple products of the same manufacturer has the same logo, as is the case here and hence feature based recognition is bound to fail. But if you do the same with text that would not be the case as text will be distinctive for a particular product and a manufacturer.